# Drawメソッドが呼び出されないです。おそらくinvalidate()の位置が関係していると思うけど分かりません

Tags: java, android, kotlin

#### 実現したいこと

リアルタイム顔検出して、輪郭を四角く囲う

#### 前提

KotlinとML Kitを使用して、リアルタイムで顔検出をして輪郭を四角く囲おうとしています。
一通り実装し終わったので実行したのですが、輪郭を四角く囲えていませんでした。

#### 発生している問題

analyzeメソッドにあるログだと輪郭の座標は取得できて変数に代入できているのですが、
onDrawメソッドにあるログだと代入した数字がもってこれていないことが分かりました。(変数は持ってこれています。)

また、onDrawメソッドが三回呼び出されてからanalyzeメソッドにいっています。(理由がわからない)

座標を指定(100, 200, 100, 200)みたいに指定したところ、線が表示されたので座標をonDrawメソッドにもってくることができると解決するかと思われます。

#### 試したこと

- 同期処理になっていないのかと思い、analyzeメソッドに同期処理を実装しました。
- 座標を指定したら線を表示させることに成功した。
- invalidate()の位置を調整した。
- setWillNotDraw()も試した

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

minSdk 21
targetSdk 32
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"

#### 該当のソースコード

MainActivity

```
import android.Manifest
import android.content.Context
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.media.FaceDetector
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.util.Size
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.camera.core.*
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture
import androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner
import java.util.concurrent.Executors


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var cameraProviderFuture: ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider>

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "CameraXBasic"
        private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            startCamera()
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), 10)
            startCamera()
        }
    }

    private fun allPermissionsGranted() = REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(baseContext, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }


    fun startCamera() {
        val finder = findViewById<PreviewView>(R.id.viewFinder)
        cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
            val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            var preview: Preview = Preview.Builder()
                .build()

            var cameraSelector: CameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
                .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
                .build()

            val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                .setTargetResolution(Size(640, 480))
                .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                .build()

            val context = this
            imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(), ImageAnalyzer(context = context, attrs = null))

            try {
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()
                var camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this as LifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, imageAnalysis, preview,)
                Log.d(TAG, "camera set.")
                preview.setSurfaceProvider(finder.createSurfaceProvider(camera.cameraInfo))
            } catch (exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }
}
```

ImageAnalyzer

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.*
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis
import androidx.camera.core.ImageProxy
import com.google.mlkit.vision.common.InputImage
import com.google.mlkit.vision.face.FaceContour
import com.google.mlkit.vision.face.FaceDetection
import com.google.mlkit.vision.face.FaceDetectorOptions
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import okhttp3.Dispatcher
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList

class ImageAnalyzer(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer,
    View(context, attrs) {

    private val paint = Paint().apply {
        color = Color.GREEN
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        strokeWidth = 5f
    }

    private var bounds = Rect(0, 0, 0, 0)

    @SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
    override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {
        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "analyze start.")
        val mediaImage = imageProxy.image

        if (mediaImage != null) {
            Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "image true.")
            val image =
                InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees)
            val realTimeOpts = FaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
                .setContourMode(FaceDetectorOptions.CONTOUR_MODE_ALL)
                .build()
            val detector = FaceDetection.getClient(realTimeOpts)
            detector.process(image)
                .addOnSuccessListener { faces ->
                    for (face in faces) {
                        bounds.set(
                            face.boundingBox.left,
                            face.boundingBox.top,
                            face.boundingBox.right,
                            face.boundingBox.bottom
                        )
                        invalidate()
                        Log.d(TAG, "Face detected:$bounds")
                    }
                    imageProxy.close()
                    Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "imagePrroxy closed.")
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                    Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "process failed.")
                }
        } else {
            Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "image false.")
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Analyzer finish")
    }


    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {

        Log.d(TAG, "bounds:$bounds")
        canvas?.drawRect(
            bounds.left.toFloat(),
            bounds.top.toFloat(),
            bounds.right.toFloat(),
            bounds.bottom.toFloat(),
            paint
        )
        Log.d(TAG, "onDraw called")
    }
}
```

Log

```
2023-03-08 14:04:42.097 5600-5760/com.example.facedetection V/FaceDetectorV2Jni: detectFacesImageByteBufferMultiPlanes.start()
2023-03-08 14:04:42.108 5600-5740/com.example.facedetection D/TransportRuntime.SQLiteEventStore: Storing event with priority=DEFAULT, name=FIREBASE_ML_SDK for destination cct
2023-03-08 14:04:42.112 5600-5740/com.example.facedetection D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler: Upload for context TransportContext(cct, DEFAULT, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MGNjL2xvZy9iYXRjaD9mb3JtYXQ9anNvbl9wcm90bzNc) is already scheduled. Returning...
2023-03-08 14:04:42.128 5600-5760/com.example.facedetection V/FaceDetectorV2Jni: detectFacesImageByteBuffer.end()
2023-03-08 14:04:42.129 5600-5600/com.example.facedetection D/ContentValues: Face detected:Rect(370, 95 - 890, 679)
2023-03-08 14:04:42.130 5600-5600/com.example.facedetection D/CameraXBasic: imagePrroxy closed.
2023-03-08 14:04:42.130 5600-5739/com.example.facedetection D/CameraXBasic: analyze start.
2023-03-08 14:04:42.130 5600-5739/com.example.facedetection D/CameraXBasic: image true.
2023-03-08 14:04:42.131 5600-5739/com.example.facedetection D/ContentValues: Analyzer finish
2023-03-08 14:04:42.131 5600-5744/com.example.facedetection V/FaceDetectorV2Jni: detectFacesImageByteBufferMultiPlanes.start()
2023-03-08 14:04:42.136 5600-5740/com.example.facedetection D/TransportRuntime.SQLiteEventStore: Storing event with priority=DEFAULT, name=FIREBASE_ML_SDK for destination cct
2023-03-08 14:04:42.139 5600-5740/com.example.facedetection D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler: Upload for context TransportContext(cct, DEFAULT, MSRodHRwczovL2ZpcmViYXNlbG9nZ2luZy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MGNjL2xvZy9iYXRjaD9mb3JtYXQ9anNvbl9wcm90bzNc) is already scheduled. Returning...
2023-03-08 14:04:42.161 5600-5744/com.example.facedetection V/FaceDetectorV2Jni: detectFacesImageByteBuffer.end()
2023-03-08 14:04:42.163 5600-5600/com.example.facedetection D/ContentValues: Face detected:Rect(376, 98 - 892, 696)
2023-03-08 14:04:42.163 5600-5600/com.example.facedetection D/CameraXBasic: imagePrroxy closed.
2023-03-08 14:04:42.169 5600-5739/com.example.facedetection D/CameraXBasic: analyze start.
2023-03-08 14:04:42.169 5600-5739/com.example.facedetection D/CameraXBasic: image true.
2023-03-08 14:04:42.170 5600-5739/com.example.facedetection D/ContentValues: Analyzer finish
```